# How do I add a microphone mount to my camera?

Tags: accessories, tripod-socket

I am purchasing [this microphone](https://www.amazon.ca/Opteka-VM-200-Condenser-Microphone-Camcorders/dp/B007QV1E7Y/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1488925246&sr=8-1&keywords=camcorder%20stereo%20microphone) for my camera.

Unfortunately my camera does not have a mount on top for it. I use my camera mounted on a tripod.

What options are available to me to facilitate using this microphone?

Are there glue on mounts? I would have no problem adhering a mount to my camera using a high strength glue. Is there a product that already fits this role?

Also I don't even know what the different mounts are called...

It seems like there is a screw mount and a slide in square mount. What a the technical terms for these different kinds of mounts. Surely that would help me in finding a product that would let me augment my camera.

My camera does have a tripod shoe on the bottom.

Comment: The photo of that mic shows it attached to the camera hotshoe, which is I think the "slide in square mount" you refer to.  What make & model camera do you have?

Comment: Welcome to Photography at Stack Exchange, ScottF! It might help if you could provide the specific camera model in the question. Unless you can demonstrate how one might need a microphone for still photography the question might also be better suited for video.stackexchange.com since this group is dedicated to still photography only.

Comment: @MichaelClark has a good point that this is probably a video question (though I briefly considered mounting a directional mic on my SLR for recording birdsong and shooting stills).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This microphone mounts on your camera's [**hot shoe**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_shoe) (which is usually used for add-on flash units).

If your camera does not have a hot shoe for external flash, and you said you have no problem using adhesive to mount your microphone to your camera, you can get a **cold shoe** flash mount, which is just the physical "square slot" mount without electrical connections for flashes, and attach the cold shoe to the camera.

[image] [image]
<sup>Examples of inexpensive cold shoes: simple stamped steel (left); with built-in clamp (right)</sup>

Alternately, you can use your camera's tripod mount socket to mount your camera to an adapter plate (often called "cheese plates", especially in videography contexts) that extends to the side of the camera, and mount a cold shoe or other useful mount to the plate, and then mount the microphone to it. This has the benefit of not gluing or adhering a hunk of metal to your camera.

Nearly *all* cameras these days have tripod mount sockets, which is a 1/4-20 threaded hole (1/4 inch diameter, 20 thread-per-inch). Note that this is even true for cameras countries that use the metric system; the entire camera industry has standardized on the 1/4-20 (and its 3/8-16 sibling) for tripod mount. From [Wikipedia's Tripod article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripod_(photography)):

> Per ISO 1222:2010, the current tripod screw thread standard for attaching the camera calls for a 1/4-20 UNC or 3/8-16 UNC thread. Most consumer cameras are fitted with 1/4-20 UNC threads. Larger, professional cameras and lenses may be fitted with 3/8-16 UNC threads, plus a removable 1/4-20 UNC adapter, allowing them to be mounted on a tripod using either standard.

You can easily make such an adapter plate with a block of metal or wood, and a handful of 1/4-20 screws and nuts from the hardware store.

Comment: My camera does have a tripod screw hole on the bottom.

Comment: A "flash bracket" is what to look for. There are some which can bend around, so could hold the microphone above the camera.